# Apply a "row banding" theme to a range

Tags: google-apps-script, syntax, enums, google-sheets

I am a beginner to Google Apps Script but use it to automate some simple repeating tasks. I have several spreadsheets I am copying content on a weekly basis and export them as an `.xls` file that I send to my client.

I am trying to apply alternating colors to a range I copy from another sheet but I completely got stuck. How to correctly set `bandingTheme` with the `applyRowBanding` method? What is the right syntax I should use in the last line of my code?

My code:

```
function copyRange (SourceSSID, SourceRange, TargetSheetName, bandingTheme) {
  var sheetSource = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SourceSSID);
  var sheetTarget = SpreadsheetApp.openById("bla-bla");
  var source =  sheetSource.getRange(SourceRange);
  var target_ss = sheetTarget.getSheetByName(TargetSheetName);
  var values = source.getValues();
  var target = target_ss.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length);
  target.clear();

  target.setValues(values);

  target.applyRowBanding ();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your method argument `bandingTheme` is one of the enums listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding-theme), you can simply apply it, using the [`apply___Banding(BandingTheme theme)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#applyRowBanding(BandingTheme)) method signature:

```
target.applyRowBanding(bandingTheme);
```

The above is equivalent to this line, per documentation:

```
target.applyRowBanding(bandingTheme, true, false);
```

(In other words, the default behavior is to color the header but not the footer, in addition to alternating row colors.)

You can ensure no existing themes were previously present (only a single kind of alternating colors - be it from columns OR rows - can be present at any given time, else an error is thrown).

```
target.getBandings().forEach(function (banding) {
  banding.remove();
});
/**
 * set the new banding theme
 * ....
 */
```

If you wanted to set a custom banding theme, you can do so by starting from one of the theme designs. Note that the `apply___Banding` methods return the [`Banding`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding.html) object that they applied. If you bind this return value (or chain the methods), then you can modify it using its class methods.

```
const newBanding = target.applyRowBanding(SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme.BLUE);
// newBanding is now a Banding that was instantiated with the "Blue" template.
// Color the header column:
newBanding.setHeaderColumnColor('teal');

// Equivalent:
target.applyRowBanding(SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme.BLUE).setHeaderColumnColor('teal');
```

Note that setting colors for non-header columns in a row-banding theme doesn't work. Likewise for setting non-header row colors in a column-banding theme.

---

If your `bandingTheme` argument isn't one of the theme enums, then you will have to provide more details about what it is in order to get answers that help you convert it into the available Spreadsheet Service methods.

Comment: Actually it was my issue - what to use as `bandingTheme` argument. I tried to use string argument `(like 'BLUE', 'BandingTheme.BLUE'`), or as `BandingTheme.BLUE`.

Comment: @EugeneCherepanov as shown in my answer, you must use the proper scope for class enums: `SpreadsheetApp` is the entry point for all classes related to the Apps Script Spreadsheet Service.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that removes existing bandings and then applies alternating colors to an entire sheet.  Please refer to Google Apps Script [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) and [Banding](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding) Class documentation for support.

```
function applyRowBanding() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.getBandings().forEach(banding => banding.remove());
  range.applyRowBanding(SpreadsheetApp.BandingTheme.LIGHT_GREY, true, false);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is banding an alias for alternating colors?

Comment: Banding is shading of alternating rows in a worksheet.  Banding may applied to all columns or a particular column.