# Google Apps Script SpreadsheetApp Banding Class - How to access these methods

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to access the Banding Class of methods for the SpreadsheetApp.  This is not how to simply apply banding.  Instead, I am trying to get the data related to a sheet that banding has been applied to.

Here is the Developers Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding

I can use .getBandings() but this simply confirms whether or not a banding exits in the sheet.  There is no data as to the details of that banding.  For example, I would like to return the range of the banding.

I also learned that when a banding is applied, the background color of the cell stays default, so I cannot utilize those methods to determine the details.

Here is the link to a Sheet with banding applied.  I have added a few lines of script to show what getBandings() returns.  Feel free to make a copy.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xRuwE8moueSY5ZizZcy6KPkVmhJmOITN9Bql7XgHY3g/edit#gid=0

Any advice on how to access/utilize the methods in the Banding class would be appreciated.

---

From a comment to an answer

I am trying figure out the list of methods that would open up that class in SpreadsheetApp. I have experimented with SpreadsheetApp, getActiveSheet, getSheetByName, getRange and more. I cannot figure out how to open up that set of commands in the Banding class.

Comment: I know you are looking for answers but I have been using Google Sheets for years now and never noticed Banding.  I guess because I can't find any Menu option that applies banding.  And if you look at Spreadsheet and Sheet class you can getBandings() but I don't see any way of applying bandings.  How do you use it?

Comment: Banding within a sheet is the "Alternating Colors" option under the Format in the menu.  When trying to accomplish the same task with Apps Script, it is called Banding.  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),.getRange(row, column).applyColumnBanding(bandingTheme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, I would like to return the range of the banding.

To get the range of a banding use the [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding#getrange) method of Class Banding

---

getBandings() returns an interable object. Below is a simple example of how to get the address of the range of a banding. It assumes that the spreadsheet has at least one banding.

```
function myFunction(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bandings = spreasheet.getBandings();
  var range = bandings[0].getRange();
  Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
}
```

Related

- [Apply a "row banding" theme to a range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51603390/1595451)

Comment: Thanks Ruben for the comment.  Unfortunately, you have provided the same link I did.  I am trying figure out the list of methods that would open up that class in SpreadsheetApp.    I have experimented with SpreadsheetApp, getActiveSheet, getSheetByName, getRange and more.  I cannot figure out how to open up that set of commands in the Banding class.

Comment: Thanks Ruben!  That is what I was missing.  ugh.  I just was not making the connection and could not figure out how to get that.  Thank you!